# CRM 2013: Unable to delete CRM solution (Holding Solution approach)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

We have our CRM environment on CRM 2013 SP1. We have a 'managed' solution installed in a target environment. Now, an attribute (Lookup ) was removed from the unmanaged solution in Development environment. Since the deletes do not automatically work, we tried deleting the Attribute/Relationship manually from the Target environment, however, it did not work because of the managed properties of the solution.

We then tried using the 'Holding solution' concept as explained in this article:
[Holding Solution Approach](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/gonzaloruiz/archive/2012/05/07/crm-2011-deleting-attributes-entities-relationships-or-optionsets-from-managed-solutions.aspx)

We have created a solution in Development environment with same publisher, and same components as the original solution(ABC_Holding for example). The attribute/relationship was removed in Dev environment. Importing this solution into the target environment was successful. Now, to remove the attribute/realtionship from the target environment, we tried removing the Original Managed solution. This is resulting in an 'unexpected' error.

Below is the error message.

```
 <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
 <Message>EntityRelationshipRolesUninstallHandler.DeleteComponent should never be called. 
 EntityRelationshipRoles should be deleted by EntityRelationshipService.Delete
</Message>
```

Has anyone seen this error before? Is there a way to get around this ?? Please assist.

Thanks

Rajesh